# Secure way to authenticate a user to a website without password

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have a problem to solve for, which I have searched for a good way to do; a pattern or a framework to use.

*First of all, I will describe the problem...*
We have a service user which has to support customers in a target web application.

To do that, the AD account of the service user gets linked to several customer accounts of the target application. The service user shall not know the password of the customer accounts but should be able to authenticate in the target application by clicking on the user account.

This should be the workflow:

1. A service user logs into an ASP.NET MVC webpage using his Active Directory Account.  The ASP.NET MVC webpage is just for showing users which are linked to the AD account of the service user.
2. After login of the service user he will see a list of customer accounts which comes from a database, which are linked to his AD account
3. The service user clicks on the name of a customer account and gets authenticated and redirected to the target web application without knowledge of the password from the customer user

*My Question is:*
How can i authenticate the customer user in a secure way(!) without knowing the password of the customer user from a different website/domain as the target web application? I thought about something like token authentication?

[image: Authentication Workflow]

Comment: Why is the service user trying to authenticate as the customer? Shouldn't it perform actions under its own identity, rather than impersonating the customer?

Comment: For sure! But this is the requirement of the customer for whom i develop this. It would be harder for now to change the authorization in the legacy ASP.NET WepPages application...